# Maximum Independent set of sparse graphs with few triangles

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, random-graphs

Notations used

1. $\alpha(G) = $  Max sized independent set of graph $G$.
2. $n(G) = $ Number of vertex in graph $G$.

*Theorem* (by Ajtai et al.): For a [triangle-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle-free_graph) graph $G$ and max degree being $\Delta$,

$$\alpha(G) \geq \frac{n(G)}{8\Delta}\log_2\Delta.$$

For a general graph, $\alpha(G) \geq n(G)/(\Delta+1)$, hence the above result is an improvement by a factor of $O(\log_2\Delta)$. The proof of the above theorem is heavily uses the triangle-free property of the graph.

*Theorem* : For a graph $G$ having maximum degree $\Delta$ and having at most T triangles,
$$\alpha(G) \geq \frac{n(G)}{10\Delta}\Bigg(\log_2\Delta - \frac{1}{2}\log_2\Big(\frac{T}{n(G)}\Big)\Bigg)$$

**I am not able to find the proof for the above theorem**. It would be great if someone could point me to a book or paper which proves the above theorem

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In paper (arxiv.org/pdf/math.CO/0404325), paragraph above lemma 6 claims that following theorem is proved in Random Graphs, 1st edition by Bollobas. Sadly, I have only the 2nd edition of the book and I am not able to find its proof in the 2nd edition.

Comment: This may contain it: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895691900804

Comment: @PéterKomjáth: The above link doesn't deal with graphs with few triangles.